# SpringXD Stream "batch identifier"

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-xd

In my project, we have the following processes:

1. A spring batch job that reads X records from a DB table and dumps
   them in rabbitmq as a topic
2. A spring XD stream that takes the messages from the queue and writes them to a file
3. Another stream takes the same records as above from the queue and puts them in a table
4. An independent spring batch job runs about 6 hours later that sends the file generated in (2) to a third party vendor

I want to make sure that the stream in (2) has finished processing. I was thinking of two options:

- Have a dummy record at the end of the records in the queue which indicates completion of records (hacky, would prefer not to do this)
- Have some sort of a batch identifier and verify that the queue does not contain any message with that batch identifier (How will this work?)

Any alternative suggestions on this problem? Thanks in advance!